# Are there any geology only related educational institutions?

Tags: geology, education

I'm not looking for college recommendations or which is the best, so I'm not asking for opinions on which institutions are the best. What I would like to know is if there are specific places that someone could go where they can just focus on geology related fields only. And only take classes that pertained to acquiring enough education to work in a geology related field.

Comment: Hi ! Well, keep in mind that Geosciences work hand in hand with physics, chemistry, biology, mathematics, information science, and i am sure i forgot something. A broad foundation is necessariy, before one can decide which direction to take for further studies/learning etc. In parts of Europe (Germany) one can just attend lectures. e.g. introductory lectures in earth's dynamics for example. Assuming a certain base of knowledge.

Comment: Thanks. That is helpful. Good to know.

Comment: geology only probably not, geology focused yes, as a college you have to educate students in more than just their major so some diversification is almost necessary. if you are looking for a good geology school I recommend the south dakota school of mines, https://www.sdsmt.edu/ it has a very geosciences focused.

Comment: Ort your countries geological survey (www.usgs.gov) might may be worth contacting ...

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have heard of SDSMT. I also wondered about the USGS. I shall check on those.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you limit yourself? You could just go to a regular university and enroll in the geology degree program. In some countries (like Germany) you would then only take courses necessary to become a geologist (including the math and physics you need to understand for it). In some other countries (e.g, the United States) you'd have to take other courses for "breadth requirements" as well, but most of your courses would still be in geology.

The fact that a regular university *also* offers courses in other areas doesn't really matter that much, or does it?